# Nil drawable for layer <Metal Layer: 0x17069b850>

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, calayer

While running my app getting `Nil drawable for layer <Metal Layer: 0x17069b850>` error come back from `MKMapViewController`.

Comment: is the MKMapViewController not showing on the screen(MKMapViewController place inside of Scrollview and it is off the screen)?

Comment: Any solution for this since this was posted? I'm getting huge lag when closing a view controller with a MKMapView in it.

Comment: Same here. Adding a child viewcontroller and resizing the map, it takes 4 seconds ...

Comment: Navigattion takes time if the controller contains `MKMapView`, also app stuck showing `Nil drawable for layer` warning on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same when I press a cancel button in one of my view controllers (without using any metal in my app). The process of calling the button handler is also very long....